# Z-Index Not Working For Relative Divs

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have divs that have a background image, and I set them to be positioned relative with a high z-index. There are four of them and they should be seen under good examples [here](http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/web_design.html). However, they do not show up in the document, my guess because of a stacking issue

My HTML code

```
<div id="white_house" class="ext_image"><a href="http://www.whitehouse.gov" target="_blank"><div class="view_site"></div></a></div>

<div id="abc" class="ext_image"><a href="http://www.abc.com" target="_blank"><div  class="view_site"></div></a></div>

<div id="quartz" class="ext_image"><a href="http://www.qz.com" target="_blank"><div class="view_site"></div></a></div>

<div id="usatoday" class="ext_image"><a href="http://www.usatoday.com" target="_blank"><div class="view_site"></div></a></div>
```

CSS (only one id is shown but same general style applies)

```
#ext_image {
position:relative;
z-index:5000;   
}

#white_house{
width:490px;
height:231px;
 background:url('http://webmaster.tsaprotectandserve.com/new_design/images/white_house_website.PNG') no-repeat center;
background-size:100%; 
float:left;
margin-bottom:20px; 
position:relative;
z-index:5000;  
}
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle with your code and images that work.

Comment: Yup - Need some more context. It could be many of things, but `float` can have stacking issues when using `z-index`. Let's see a Fiddle and I'm sure we can help.

Comment: I'm honestly not too familiar with fiddle and if I put one together, I'm afraid I might leave out certain elements since my page has a large hierarchy. The page with the problem is http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/web_design.html#good_examples. Is that sufficient? There should be four images under the heading and subheading.

Comment: just checking: css selects on `#ext_image`, but `ext_image` only ever appears as a class

Comment: That was a silly mistake on my part, but I changed it and it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: set .png and not .PNG always use lowercase.. also set whitehouse to 5001.

Comment: The links to your background images are throwing 404s, so fix those. I don't see any need for z-index here at all.

Comment: Turns out I had the wrong link to the image. The reason I used .PNG which I still used and is working is because the program I used to get those images (Grab) saves them as .PNG and only .PNG seemed to work as the url. Will that cause problems later on?